# What is an appropriate PDF page size (dpi) for iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, pdf, dpi

In case of drawing PDF with Quartz and supporting enlarging it (using tilted layer),
What is an appropriate PDF page size (dpi) for iPad?

Currently, I'm drawing 3 viewes (previous, current, next) on a scrollview for a PDF file.
When the scrollview is scrolled and the current page is changed, the old previous or next view is removed and a new or previous view is created and added.

7,8,9 - (go to the next page) -> 8,9,10

In the above situation, 100dpi PDF is ok. But PDFs over 150dpi encounter crash (memory problem).

In case of 150dpi, first 3 pages (previous, current, next) are successfully created and drawn but the app encounters crash after turning over pages three or four times.

Please let me know the size (dpi) if you made iPad apps viewing PDFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've probably found out, it depends on the content. After some trial and error, I settled on around 100dpi. That was for some quite visual content - mainly text content with some imagery could probably go a lot higher.

If you're having memory issues at 150dpi and 100 works fine, I'd stick at 100.